# SQL Server: column returns specific where value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Newbie question here, thanks for your help in advance.

I'm trying to return a table of prices by PropertyID where UnitTypeID = 3, another column where UnitTypeID = 4, another column where UnitTypeID = 5.  Basically creating a matrix of prices by PropertyID and UnitTypeID.

I am able to create a table that presents just one UnitTypeID:

```
SELECT PropertyID, price
FROM table
WHERE UnitTypeID = 3
```

and another query where

```
SELECT PropertyID, price
FROM table
WHERE UnitTypeID = 4
```

Etc, etc.

But I want to create a single table where the first column is all the FacilityID's, second column is the corresponding price when UnitTypeID = 3, third column is the corresponding price when UnitTypeID = 4, fourth column is the corresponding price when UnitTypeID = 5.

Thanks so much.

**EDIT**: tried to use PIVOT function but getting a series of nulls.  There are many other unittypeIDs that are returning NULLs.  How do I limit to just unitTypeID of 3, 4, 5?

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT *
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              futr_int_id,
              futr_int_FacilityId,
              futr_int_unittypeid,
              futr_dtm_effectivedate,
              futr_mny_monthlyrent,
              futr_bit_Deleteflag,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY futr_int_FacilityId, futr_int_unittypeid 
                                 ORDER BY futr_dtm_effectivedate DESC) AS rn
          FROM 
              FacilityUnitTypesRent) AS T
    WHERE 
        rn = 1
        AND futr_bit_Deleteflag = 0) last_rate
PIVOT
    (SUM(last_rate.futr_mny_MonthlyRent)
     FOR last_rate.futr_int_unittypeID IN ([3], [4], [5])
    ) AS pivot_table
```

[Pivot Table Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8nVq.png)

**EDIT 2**: one thing worth mentioning is that the pricing table includes all historical prices and I'm only interested in the current price, hence the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         --futr_int_id,
         futr_int_FacilityId,
         futr_int_unittypeid,
         futr_dtm_effectivedate,
         futr_mny_monthlyrent,
         futr_bit_Deleteflag,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY futr_int_FacilityId, futr_int_unittypeid 
                            ORDER BY futr_dtm_effectivedate DESC) AS rn
     FROM 
         FacilityUnitTypesRent) AS T
WHERE 
    rn = 1
    AND futr_bit_Deleteflag = 0) last_rate
```

This seems to be the tricky part of this pivot.

```
PIVOT (
  SUM(last_rate.futr.futr_mny_MonthlyRent)
  FOR UnitTypeID IN (3, 4, 5)
  )
```

When I pivot with a more standard subquery as suggested by one of the respondents:

```
SELECT *
    FROM    
    (SELECT 
                futr_int_FacilityId,
                futr_int_unittypeid,
                futr_mny_monthlyrent 
        FROM FacilityUnitTypesRent
        WHERE futr_bit_Deleteflag = 0
    ) rate

PIVOT (
  SUM(rate.futr_mny_MonthlyRent)
  FOR rate.futr_int_UnitTypeId IN ([3], [4], [5])
  ) AS pivot_table
```

the pivot returns what I expected in terms of layout, but because I use the SUM() function in the pivot, I get the sum of all the historical pricing.  I just want the most recent price, so need to incorporate the

```
row_number() over(partition by futr_int_FacilityId, 
    futr_int_unittypeid ORDER BY futr_dtm_effectivedate DESC
```

When I do incorporate, I am left with a table with NULL values galore.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q091d.png)

Thanks so much for the continued support

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: sounds like you are looking for Pivot operator... 
Follow the link for more details and example https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-pivot/

Comment: Tried pivot, but not quite what I need.  Getting nulls for unittypeIDs not included in my pivot.

Answer (score 0):

To `PIVOT` as intended, you need to prevent unique IDs from your selection. Base on the picture, the `futr_int_id` appears to be the primary key or some type of unique identifier.

If we keep it simple, this is likely what you want:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT PropertyID, price, UnitTypeID, futr_mny_monthlyrent
  FROM table
  )
PIVOT (
  SUM(last_rate.futr.futr_mny_MonthlyRent)
  FOR UnitTypeID IN (3, 4, 5)
  )
```

To apply it to your use case, it appears removing `futr_int_id` would likely be a good solution although you may want to use `fur_bit_Deleteflag = 0` in the inner most subquery depending on your use case.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(SELECT futr_int_FacilityId,
                futr_int_unittypeid,
                futr_dtm_effectivedate,
                futr_mny_monthlyrent,
                futr_bit_Deleteflag
        FROM 
        (SELECT --futr_int_id,
                futr_int_FacilityId,
                futr_int_unittypeid,
                futr_dtm_effectivedate,
                futr_mny_monthlyrent,
                futr_bit_Deleteflag,
                row_number() over(partition by futr_int_FacilityId, 
                futr_int_unittypeid ORDER BY futr_dtm_effectivedate DESC) 
                AS rn
        FROM FacilityUnitTypesRent

    ) as T
    WHERE rn = 1
    AND futr_bit_Deleteflag = 0
    ) last_rate

PIVOT(
    SUM(last_rate.futr_mny_MonthlyRent)
    FOR last_rate.futr_int_unittypeID IN (
        [3],
        [4],
        [5])

) AS pivot_table
```

Comment: You are a kind soul, thanks for taking the time to help.  Sending good karma your way.

Comment: On thing I forgot to mention is that the price table includes all historical prices.  I'm trying to get just the most recent price, hence the code in the original subquery:

Comment: SELECT *
   FROM 
   (SELECT 
     --futr_int_id,
     futr_int_FacilityId,
     futr_int_unittypeid,
     futr_dtm_effectivedate,
     futr_mny_monthlyrent,
     futr_bit_Deleteflag,
     row_number() over(partition by futr_int_FacilityId, futr_int_unittypeid ORDER BY futr_dtm_effectivedate DESC) AS rn
   FROM FacilityUnitTypesRent

  ) as T
  WHERE rn = 1
  AND futr_bit_Deleteflag = 0
  ) last_rate)

Comment: I think it’s one of two things. You may need to unselect your `rn` column. More likely, if you have the `delete_flag == 0` predicate in your outer inner loop, similar to my answer, you may be filtering out most of your results. It’s hard to say without data.